# Java Spring Boot - forgot password - email service with velocity?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, velocity

I am fairly new to Java and Spring Boot. I've started to try and map out the various functions and parameters.

3. Forgot password -- email sending.

   ```
       //__ send email notification
       SimpleEmailService.generateEmail("forgotPasswordTemplate", data);
   ```

this is what the old email service was like -- what would be the equivlant with Java Spring Boot? -- What libs to import?

```
package controller;

import org.apache.velocity.Template;
import org.apache.velocity.VelocityContext;
import org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessagePreparator;

import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;

import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

import java.io.StringWriter;

public class SimpleEmailService {
   private static JavaMailSender mailSender;
   private static VelocityEngine velocityEngine;

   public void setMailSender(JavaMailSender mailSender) {
      this.mailSender = mailSender;
   }

   public void setVelocityEngine(VelocityEngine velocityEngine) {
      this.velocityEngine = velocityEngine;
   }

   public static void generateEmail(final String templateType, final BasicDBObject user) {
      MimeMessagePreparator preparator = new MimeMessagePreparator() {
         public void prepare(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws Exception { 
             String velocityTemplateName = null;
             String subject = null;

            if(templateType.equals("forgotPasswordTemplate")){
                 velocityTemplateName = "forgot_password";
                 subject = "Forgot Password";
                 user.put("imgPath", "http://livesite.com/images/emails/forgot_password/");
            }


            if(templateType.equals("registerTemplate")){
                velocityTemplateName = "registration_confirmation";
                subject = "Registration";
                user.put("imgPath", "http://livesite.com/images/emails/registration_confirmation/");
            }


            MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage);
                message.setTo("my@test.com");
                message.setFrom("hello@test.com"); // could be parameterized...


                message.setSubject(subject);

            VelocityContext model = new VelocityContext();
                model.put("user", user);            

            String text = applyTemplate(model, velocityTemplateName+".vm");
                message.setText(text, true);
         }
      };
      mailSender.send(preparator);
   }

   public static String applyTemplate(VelocityContext data, String templateName){                  
       StringWriter sw= new StringWriter();        
       Template t = velocityEngine.getTemplate("net/velocity/templates/"+templateName);
       t.merge(data, sw);
       return sw.toString();                        
   }
}
```

---

This is what my current code base looks like -- I essentially want to power a reactjs build with an api -- so in terms of architecture -- the /api would be a get service -- the other's are post's from forms.

--

```
package controller;


import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.apache.tomcat.util.log.SystemLogHandler;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import domain.Account;
import repo.AccountRepository;


@RestController
public class MyService {

    @Autowired
    private AccountRepository accountRepository;


    @RequestMapping(value = "/api", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @CrossOrigin(origins = {"*"})
    public ResponseEntity<?> index(@RequestParam(value="name", required=false, defaultValue="admin1") String name) throws Exception {
            Account acc = accountRepository.findByUsername(name);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(acc, HttpStatus.OK);
    }




    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @CrossOrigin(origins = {"*"})
    public ResponseEntity<?> login(
            @RequestParam(value="email", required=false, defaultValue="email") String email,
            @RequestParam(value="password", required=false, defaultValue="password") String password, 
            HttpServletRequest request
            ) throws  Exception {
            List<Account> acc = accountRepository.findByEmail(email);

            HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
            session.setAttribute("user", acc);

            System.out.println("logged>>>"+acc);
            System.out.println("session>>>"+session);

            return new ResponseEntity<>(acc, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @CrossOrigin(origins = {"*"})
    public ResponseEntity<?> logout(
            HttpServletRequest request
            ) throws  Exception {

            HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
            List<Account> acc = (List<Account>) session.getAttribute("user");

            session.removeAttribute("user");            

            System.out.println("logout>>>"+acc);
            System.out.println("session>>>"+session);

            return new ResponseEntity<>(acc, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/forgot", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @CrossOrigin(origins = {"*"})
    public ResponseEntity<?> forgot(
            @RequestParam(value="email", required=false, defaultValue="email") String email
            ) throws  Exception {
            List<Account> acc = accountRepository.findByEmail(email);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(acc, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @CrossOrigin(origins = {"*"})
    public ResponseEntity<?> edit(
            @RequestParam(value="username", required=false, defaultValue="username") String username,
            @RequestParam(value="password", required=false, defaultValue="password") String password,
            @RequestParam(value="email", required=false, defaultValue="email") String email
            ) throws  Exception {
            Account acc = accountRepository.findByUsername(username);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(acc, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @CrossOrigin(origins = {"*"})
    public ResponseEntity<?> register(
            @RequestParam(value="username", required=false, defaultValue="username") String username,
            @RequestParam(value="password", required=false, defaultValue="password") String password,
            @RequestParam(value="email", required=false, defaultValue="email") String email
            ) throws  Exception {
        Account checkAccount = accountRepository.findByUsername(username);
        System.out.println("checkAccount>>>"+checkAccount);
        if (checkAccount == null) {
            try {               
                // if not create some
                Account newAcc = accountRepository.saveAndFlush(new Account(
                            username, 
                            password, 
                            email
                        ));
                System.out.println("newAcc>>>"+checkAccount);
                return new ResponseEntity<>(newAcc, HttpStatus.OK);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("error adding user>>>"+checkAccount);
                return new ResponseEntity<>(e, HttpStatus.OK);
            }
        }else{
            // String e = "user exists";
            System.out.println("user already exists>>>"+checkAccount);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(checkAccount, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    }   

}
```

Comment: I think this tutorial could help https://www.quickprogrammingtips.com/spring-boot/how-to-send-email-from-spring-boot-applications.html  also you can read this reference https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.10.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mail   https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-email.html

Comment: Ok so it is similar - one example uses "freemarker templates" and the other "velocity" - any preferences? I have old code that uses velocity templates

Comment: See this post and also review the documentation of both template engines it will help you to choose the one that meets your requirements https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/86d87f6b8ad6816b1d98bad7ab68bcdad1bf5cf0

Comment: _ I have implemented the freemarker template

Answer (score 0):

Specifically to Spring Boot velocity support was [dropped](https://jira.spring.io/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/SPR-13795) because velocity 1 updated until 2010,here is [example of usage](http://netkiller.github.io/java/spring/boot/velocity.html) and [explanation on velocity with spring boot 1.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42109387/velocity-with-springboot-1-5-x)

This was before [velocity 2](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/2.0/) was released.

Freemarker is also supported, here's [example](http://zetcode.com/java/freemarker/#spring) with Spring Boot 1.4

So it depends on your Spring Boot version.